# How to effeciently save this kind of text into database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, insert, table

I have this kind of text and want to save it to database:

```
I. Master Text I                                            <<<Parent
   I.A. Sub Master Text I                                   <<<Child
      I.A.1.  Sub Sub Master Text I                         <<<Child Child                    
         I.A.1.a Sub Sub Sub Master Text I - Row 1          <<<Child Child Child 1
         I.A.1.b Sub Sub Sub Master Text I - Row 2          <<<Child Child Child 2
         I.A.1.c Sub Sub Sub Master Text I - Row 3          <<<Child Child Child 3

II. Master Text II
   II.A. Sub Master Text II
      II.A.1.  Sub Sub Master Text II
         II.A.1.a Sub Sub Sub Master Text II - Row 1
      II.A.2.  Sub Sub Master Text II
         II.A.2.a Sub Sub Sub Master Text II - Row 1
         II.A.2.b Sub Sub Sub Master Text II - Row 2

III. Master Text III
   III.A. Sub Master Text III
      III.A.1.  Sub Sub Master Text III
         III.A.1.a Sub Sub Sub Master Text III - Row 1
         III.A.1.b Sub Sub Sub Master Text III - Row 2
         III.A.1.c Sub Sub Sub Master Text III - Row 3
   III.B. Sub Master Text III
```

How to effeciently save these text?. There are always a `Parent` but the number of `Child` is very dynamic. I can't predict how many `child` would be exist.

I currently using a conventional `Master Table` and `Detail Table` but I have to define the number of the `Detail Table` first. So, it's not reliable for this kind of text.

My main question, How to effeciently save these text (with n child) into database and easily display it like in the example?

Comment: Start with a `(id, text, parent_id)` table, and use recursive CTEs in MySQL-8.0/MariaDB-10.2+ to retrieve the data.

Comment: It is common tree structure. So use any tree-oriented storing structire.